# Using regular expression to remove unnecessary XML tags

Tags: java, regex

I have an XML file that I want to format an XML file to remove tags like "`<scientific_max></scientific_max>`".
I used that code but it didn't work

```
String regex = "<([a-z_]+)></($1)>";
result = result.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: As always with XML and HTML, don't use regexp to do that. For XML use any XML library available out there to do that. Even a SAXParser can do the job. Regexp are not suited for that!

Comment: Right, libraries provide better support. For example, JAXB would give you a plain object with all XML properties defined on a given node.

Comment: In fact, I want to use Regular expression because the process is not too long and I have not many iterations to do. Moreover, using another third library may make the process solwer which is not good.

Comment: Is there another way to remove these tags without using third library?

Comment: Regular expressions cannot count.  Any non-trivial XML manipulation requires counting.

Comment: *"the process is not too long"*  To write a broken RegEx that is unsuited to the task?  I expect not.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on doing such tasks with regular expressions you might like to know that [back references](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) are represented as `\n` in java instead of `$n`:

```
String regex = "<([a-z_]+)></\\1>";
result = result.replaceAll(regex, "");
```

Comment: I'm afraid to say that this regex doesn't return the expected result. In fact, it didn't match my java String.

Comment: @bouhmid_tun Works fine with me. What was your string? Maybe some whitespace or line break between the tags? That's why Guillaume and others pointed out that regular expressions might be not a good idea to parse XML.

Comment: My XML file contains characters like this:
<settings><graphs><type>column</type><graph></graph></graphs><guides><guide></guide></guides></settings>
PS: I can't paste all the file lack of space but this data can give you an ideo to how my file seems.

Answer (score 1):

Java is not the best when it comes to pattern matching & String replacement on files
if you are considering this to extract data based on tags, use jaxb

if you want to make permanent change to xml you may use sed

sed -i 's/<\*scientific_max>*$//' input_xml.xml